# PWM Dimming Causes Flickering

Tags: power-supply, pwm, switch-mode-power-supply, switching, ripple

I designed a 24V PWM dimmer. Basically, it drives a 24V-LED-strip with low-side switching using a MOSFET driven by a 1-kHz-PWM having 1-100% duty-cycle.

There are no problems when the circuit is supplied with a lab-type linear power supply or 2 series-connected car batteries.

But, when we use a switching power supply (I'm sure it provides enough power), the strip flickers at around 20Hz. Interestingly, no flickering at 100% duty-cycle.

I've no chance to measure the output of the supply, because the circuit is out of my country! So I'm just trying to figure out what could be the problem.

What can cause this? If the supply has a ripple, shouldn't it show itself on 100% duty-cycle? What should/can I do?

Comment: Sounds like the SMPS gets confused by the load. Could be that the feedback loop in the SMPS gets unstable. First thing I would try is to add a decoupling cap across the output. It can also be that the SMPS changes mode (PWM/PFM) while it should not. What happens if you add a constant load to the 24 V like a resistor for making 10mA flow, or even 100 mA. That would force the SMPS in continous PWM.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks for suggestion but there's no chance to try those constant-current load conditions you've suggested because the user is not an electric-electronics guy. So I've sent a capacitor block consisting of 4 x 10000uF connected in parallel. I hope it helps. A few minutes ago, I have tested the dimmer with a Meanwell SMPS at hand and I've seen no problems. Still I'm curious about what can cause this.

Comment: I guess he uses his own power supply then and not any model you have available or supplied to him? I will tell you nothing new if I say that not all supplies are created equally (well).